# Looking for Sound Design Masters in Europe

Tags: audio, design, sound, music, production

I want to do Masters in Sound Design from Europe. I have a Bachelor's Degree in Electronics and Communication Engineering. Currently I am working as a software developer in a leading company.

Can you recommend sound design schools, which will give me an exposure in recording and production aspects as well as the science of it, preferably in Europe?

Answer (score 0):

I live in Paris and I only know a 2 years long one which has a very good reputation (it's based in *Le Mans* actually): [http://www.ircam.fr/index.php?id=961](http://www.ircam.fr/index.php?id=961&L=1)